# WiFi keeps asking for authentication, auto authenticate?

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, authentication

my Linux only machine will drop my campus WiFi on a consistence basis and ask for authentication. This can happen multiple times within a minute or a few times in an hour. Im pretty sure its something with Linux and the network since other people i know with Linux machines have the same problem, but my phone or windows laptop have no issues.

Is there a way to have the computer auto authenticate each time so i dont have to click the prompt and press enter each time? For example, have it look for a key file with the password in it and then just use that without me having to do anything?

Here is a pastebin link of dmesg output https://pastebin.com/xV110u1c

As i was writing this i was asked for authentication around 25 times, there is no pattern to it, they happen at seemingly random times.

Comment: a password manager like [BitWarden](https://bitwarden.com/)?

Comment: I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452110/wireless-connection-randomly-disconnects-and-asks-for-password-on-ubuntu).

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. But I still do not have any solution

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Try [this](https://zuoxingdong.github.io/post/2020-08-09-wifi-connection-problems-in-ubuntu/):

- Press`Alt+F2`
- Type `nm-connection-editor`
- Click on the Wi-Fi connection you want to fix and press the settings button below
- Change the Band option from `Automatic` to `B/G (2.4 GHz)`

Comment: Note this works when you still get this problem even if the auto authentication is already enabled (like happened to me). To see if it is, just: go to settings>WiFi> 3 dots in the top bar>Known Wi-Fi Networks>is the connection checked?